# May I temporarily enslave myself, to avoid missing a positive time-bound commandment?

Tags: halacha, transactions, slave-serve-eved-avadim

If I know I will be unable to do a positive time-bound commandment, may I sell myself to another Jew until the obligation passes?

Comment: You could also become a *chassan* ;-)

Answer (score 9):

You could not circumvent the obligation, as an Eved Ivri remains obligated in positive time-bound commandments. (An Eved Kena'ani is not, but to make your plan work you'd have to first become a Kena'ani.)